# Excel VBA to copy and paste values with iterations

Tags: excel, vba, iteration, montecarlo

My problem is the following:
I have some data in an Excel sheet (1 column, multiple rows) which I want to copy and paste to a new sheet (sheet2) still in a row. Values are changing all the time (Montecarlo simulations) so I need to introduce some iterations as well.

This is my code:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z2").Copy
With Sheets("sheet2")
For i = 1 To 10000
    .Range("A" & i + 1 & ":B" & i + 1 & ":C" & i + 1 & ":D" & i + 1 & ":E" & i + 1 & ":F" & i + 1 & ":G" & i + 1 & ":H" & i + 1 & ":I" & i + 1 & ":J" & i + 1 & ":K" & i + 1 & ":L" & i + 1 & ":M" & i + 1 & ":N" & i + 1 & ":O" & i + 1 & ":P" & i + 1 & ":Q" & i + 1 & ":R" & i + 1 & ":S" & i + 1 & ":T" & i + 1 & ":U" & i + 1 & ":V" & i + 1 & ":W" & i + 1 & ":X" & i + 1 & ":Y" & i + 1 & ":Z" & i + 1 & ":AA" & i + 1 & ":AB" & i + 1 & ":AC" & i + 1 & ":AD" & i + 1 & ":AE" & i + 1 & ":AF" & i + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next i
End With
```

This is of course not flexible at all since i need to specify precisely how many values I have Range("a2:z2") and I need to write all the letters corresponding to the paste columns (A to AF)

What I would like to achieve is the following:
-) Can I copy values from a column instead of a row? for example sheet 1 column A
-) Can I have the VBA to check how many values there are instead of me having to specify it ? maybe soemetimes there are 10 and sometimes 50
-) When I paste values in sheet 2 is there a way where I do not need to specify all column names but just have excel figure it out itself?

The task is basically the following:
-) Count how many values are there in column A (or whatever column contains raw data)
-) Copy those values
-) Paste values in first available row in sheet 2
-) Specify number of iterations
-) copy and past N-times corresponding to number of iterations so I have as many output rows as iterations

I am sure it should be fairly easy with a simple code, but I could not find it out myself
Thank you very much beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.PasteSpecial` property to transpose your copy selection.

```
    Dim lcol As Long
    Dim j As Integer 'Number of iterations
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim transposeRange As Range
    'Find the last value in the column
    lcol = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    j = 'Set your iteration number

    For i = 1 To j 'Count through all iterations
        Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lcol).Copy
        'Transpose the selection to paste into row
        Sheet2.Rows(i).PasteSpecial transpose:=True
    Next i
```

If you don't know the number of iterations, call this as a sub in the `Worksheet.Change` event, which will run every time the values in the column change.

Comment: Thanks!  I have tried it out and there are 2 small problems with this code: 1) the output is not store in sheet2 first row but rather in A1, B2, C3 and so on, like it was a matrix, 2) how can i tell the code to copy and paste n times (iterations) so i have multiple rows in sheet 2 in the end?

Comment: So to clarify you want all of column "A" pasted into Sheet2 row 1, and then pasted to row 2:n where n is the number of values in column "A"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , let me try again. 
Column A sheet 1 contains a number of values which can change from time to time ( so excel needs to count how many there are ) . Those values are copied into sheet2 row1 then they change j-times ( number of iterations). So after every iteration values in A are re-calculated and copied in the next available row in sheet 2 so that number of Rows=number of simulations/iterations

Comment: I think I'm following. LMK if that change works for you

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, for some reason it still does not work, I get an error related to the last line of code Sheet2.rows(i) , i have just copied and pasted your code and only changed number of iterations to 100

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: So I have tried again and now it works, thank you veyr much again for your effort. let me kindly know if I can reward your kindness in any way

Comment: Just a very last question: if I have multiple sheets with data is this macro only looking for input data in A;A in the very first sheet regardless of the name? What if I want to specify which sheet contains the input data instead?

Comment: Yeah so if you want to change the source or target sheet you can just change the `Sheet1` or `Sheet2` objects respectively